# How to make notification dissapear after click

Tags: java, android

I want to make a notification disappear after a click, I don't want to go to new Activity. This is how I build a notification :

```
public static void getSynchronizeNotification(Context context, DataResponse dataResponse){
    Bitmap Largeicon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_SYNCHRONIZE_ID);

Intent in = new Intent(String.valueOf(context));
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, in, 0);
Notification notification  = new Notification.Builder(context)
        .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setContentText("Zmiany po synchronizacji...")
        .setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().bigText(buildNotificationAfterSynchronizeText(dataResponse)))
        .setLargeIcon(Largeicon)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setVibrate(vibratePattern)
        .setSound(alarmSound)
        .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
        .build();
notification.flags = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_SYNCHRONIZE_ID, notification);
```

}

Comment: Does removing setContentIntent(pendingIntent) helps?

Comment: @KarthikCP when I etContentIntent(pendingIntent) , when I click a notification it will not happen, a notyfication dissapear when I swipe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change this :

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, in, 0);
```

to 
    `PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(), 0);`

and it works